# How to embed socks5 proxy in youtube-dl's python code?

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, socks, youtube-dl

`youtube-dl --proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:1080 $link -o   $dir`  can download video on youtube embedded socks5 proxy in bash shell.
With the following  codes,we embedded youtube-dl in python codes.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl
ydl_opts = {}
link = "some_youtube_url"
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([link])
```

How to embed socks5 proxy in python codes?
I had read the document on   https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl ,still don't know how to add socks5 proxy in youtube-dl's python codes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply set the `proxy` option:

```
ydl_opts = {
    'proxy': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080',
}
```

and keep the rest of the code unchanged.